# ERROR cannot deliver device serial request: unexpected status 400

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I've created kernel and gadget snaps for my new board.
I successfully deployed the image created by **ubuntu-image** into the emmc of my board. I can complete the device configuration (`console-conf` terminates with the message "Congratulations! This device is now registered to" ...).

Logging into my device and typing:

```
snap changes
```

I obtain the following output:

```
ID   Status  Spawn                 Ready                 Summary
1    Done    2017-01-30T09:02:08Z  2017-01-30T09:04:08Z  Initialize system state
2    Doing   2017-01-30T09:02:18Z  -                     Initialize device
The system change with ID 2 ("Initialize device") seems to be in progress.
```

More in detail with the command:

```
snap change 2
```

I obtain:

```
Status  Spawn                 Ready                 Summary
Done    2017-01-30T09:02:18Z  2017-01-30T09:04:08Z  Generate device key
Doing   2017-01-30T09:02:18Z  -                     Request device serial
......................................................................
Request device serial
2017-01-30T09:24:06Z ERROR cannot deliver device serial request: unexpected status 400
2017-01-30T09:25:09Z ERROR cannot deliver device serial request: unexpected status 400
2017-01-30T09:26:12Z ERROR cannot deliver device serial request: unexpected status 400
2017-01-30T09:27:15Z ERROR cannot deliver device serial request: unexpected status 400
[...]
```

Am I missing something in my gadget snap implementation?
Is only an ubuntu server side problem?

Comment: what board is it? is there a tutorial you followed to get where you are?

Comment: I'm using an Orange pi plus 2e. I started from https://docs.ubuntu.com/core/en/guides/build-device/image-building